# Github action script must install npm first to install packages yet others scripts don't require

Tags: npm, npm-install, github-actions

This is a working script below. The part that bothers me though is this:

```
    - name: install npm
      run: npm i npm@latest
      working-directory: ./functions
```

I have to install the latest version of NPM because otherwise I get this error:

```
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!
```

Ignoring this error doesn't install the npm packages I need to run my Firebase functions. I have other github action scripts that don't need this sort of hand holding. What am I doing wrong here?

**Full script:**

```
name: Deploy to Firebase Functions

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    # Optionally configure to run only for specific files. For example:
    paths:
    - "functions/**"

jobs:
  main:
    name: Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js 14
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: '14'
    - name: install npm
      run: npm i npm@latest
      working-directory: ./functions
    - name: install libraries
      run: npm i
      working-directory: ./functions
    - name: install firebase
      run: npm i firebase-tools -g
    - name: deploy
      run: firebase deploy --only functions --token ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_FUNCTIONS_TOKEN }}
      working-directory: ./functions
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that the `npm` version, that generated `package-lock.json` is not compatible with the `npm` version that is included in `Node.js` V14.

First option could be using such `Node.js` version in the CI, that already contains such `npm` version that is compatible with `lockfileVersion@2`. However `lockfileVersion@2` is supported from [npm version 7](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-lock-json#lockfileversion), which is part of [the latest](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/) `Node.js` version. Using an LTS version of Node is a better choice because of future security updates, so I would not recommend this option.

As second option the `packgage-lock.json` could be regenerated using a `Node.js` LTS version with `npm` V6. This way the `lockfileVersion` would be okay for the CI with Node version 14 (which is the LTS version right now). I think this is the best option.

As third option an idea is to try [npm ci](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-ci) command, but I'm not sure, if this works in this case.